# Phython panda add a new column with entries for some rowse

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to add a column with values. These values should be assigned to the dates so that I can specify for which date there should be which value or no value.

Any ideas?

**What I have**

```
portfolio

                COL   
2020-06-03      50      
2020-06-04      51      
2020-06-05      52      
2020-06-06      49      
2020-06-07      46
```

**What I want**

```
portfolio_investment

                COL1  COL2  
2020-06-03      50        
2020-06-03      50        
2020-06-03      50    50    
2020-06-04      51    50  
2020-06-05      52    50
2020-06-06      59    50
2020-06-07      56
```

Comment: What you are trying to do seems unclear. Please explain your logic.

Comment: `portfolio.loc[[list_of_dates'],'Col2'] = 50` ?

Comment: I want to say I want a new column e.g. from 2020-06-03 to 2020-06-06 with a value of e.g. 50

Comment: @CSBossmann Hmm. But in your expected output you are adding column as well as new rows?

Comment: Yeah, I want to add a new columnn and say that a certain number should be there only in certain rows. And since the rows are dates, I am trying to specify the start and end dates (rows).

I thnk somethin like the answer from @anky but instead list_of_dates I would need a way to sppecifiy the start and end date of the rows where the value should be displayed.

Does that make sense?

Comment: you can add a range in your question and edit the expected output accordingly for clarity